# Changing systemd.service TimeoutSec value to “infinity” has no effect

Tags: linux, service, centos, systemd, systemctl

My app.service file's [Service] part is the following:-

```
[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
GuessMainPID=no
ExecStart=/opt/app/appl_init.d start
ExecStop=/opt/app/appl_init.d stop
TimeoutSec=infinity
```

After which I installed the app, and the file is correctly copied to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/app.service`.

I have run `systemctl daemon-reload`, but it seems to have no effect on the start up time! It fails just as I run `systemctl start app` or `systemctl reload app.service` with the following error:-

```
Job for app.service failed because a fatal signal was delivered to the control process. See "systemctl status app.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details
```

Output of `systemctl status app` is:-

```
● app.service - ApplicationTest
   Loaded: loaded (/opt/app/appl_init.d; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Tue 2017-03-21 01:55:22 EDT; 1min 4s ago
     Docs: man:app(8)
  Process: 4126 ExecStart=/opt/app/appl_init.d start (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: Starting ApplicationTest...
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: app.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: app.service stop-final-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: app.service: control process exited, code=killed status=9
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: Failed to start ApplicationTest.
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: Unit app.service entered failed state.
Mar 21 01:55:22 centosvm systemd[1]: app.service failed.
```

Another queer thing that I noticed is when I run `systemctl show app.service -p TimeoutSec`, I don't get any result; it's blank?

I have tried doing a `systemctl reboot`, but still, no dice.

Of course, when I change the value to anything else like `TimeoutSec=5min`, then it works perfectly fine. But I really need this application to take up infinity.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you really starting a "forking" service?

Comment: Yes, I'm forking so child processes can exist as daemons that will take over after the initial setup.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TimeoutSec=0` fixed the problem.

Apparently, if you are using a version of systemd older than 229, you will need to use 0 instead of infinity to disable the timeout.